# Difference between 2 integer fields

Tags: mysql

I have two fields.

homescore and awayscore.

I need to find the difference between the two fields to order a query by.

But it could be homescore - awayscore OR awayscore - homescore.

How could I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Absolute value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) of either combination. For example `ABS(homescore - awayscore)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ABS(awayscore - homescore)` if you aren't always sure one column value is larger than the other value.